# Alter default securable for new login in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, authentication

I have two SQL Servers (Prod and Test) on the same Domain (yes, awful idea), each run SQL Server 2017.

When I create a new login on a Test server, it is granted with a Prod server address in Securable tab section.

I run command from SSMS, on a Test server:

```
CREATE LOGIN [NewTestLogin] WITH PASSWORD=N'test123@#' ,
DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master]
```

Then I open the NewTestLogin properties:

> SSMS -> Security -> Login -> NewTestLogin -> Securables tab

Here I see a Production server name instead of Test server name

My assumption is: either Test server pulls some values from the Prod server, or there are some defaults in "New Login model" that were copied from the Prod, when Test server was created from the Prod snap.

Where do I find those defaults, to change it?
Help is much appreciated.
[image]

Comment: Did you check to see if your test server (should actually be both servers if they're properly present as seperate entities) is properly listed under the search secureables (top right in your picture) => Specific objects => Object Types => Servers => Browse?

Comment: Got it!
I actually see only the Test server, while browsing the securables.
What I discovered is the error message when I choose that Test server and click OK:
   "Invalid Urn filter on server level: filter must be empty, or server attribute must be equal with the true server name"
   Googled and discovered a related issue where 
SELECT @@SERVERNAME differs from SELECT HOST_NAME which probably caused by a host name changes, after SQL Server installation.
The fix was to run
sp_dropserver 'Server1';
sp_addserver 'Server2', local
Tank you for the right direction, sir!